# the method get(class <ReportClass>) is undefined for the type ExtentReport

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i'm making selenium extent report  but i'm getting error on -  static final ExtentReports extrpt=ExtentReports.get(ReportClass.class);
        after mouse hover on get i'm getting below info.
        the method  get(class ) is undefined for the type ExtentReports 
        it's my simple java project please tell me where am i doing mistake.

```
    package DemoPacakge;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;

    public class ReportClass {
// * ReportClass .class will become TheClassName.class
        static final ExtentReports extrpt=ExtentReports.get(ReportClass.class);
        public void test()
        {

            WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://learn-automation.com/advance-selenium-reporting-with-screenshots/");
            String tile=driver.getTitle();
            Assert.assertTrue(tile.contains("learn"));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Which version of ExtentReports you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the examples section:  http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/1x/docs.html#examples

There are a few errors such as, you are not initializing the report with a "file-path". You have not instructed Extent to start a test either. Try with the below code, it should work:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class ReportClass {
    static final ExtentReports extrpt = ExtentReports.get(ReportClass.class);
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        extrpt.init("file-path.html", true);
        extrpt.config().displayCallerClass(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        extrpt.startTest("Test");

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        extrpt.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Starting FirefoxDriver..");

        driver.get("http://learn-automation.com/advance-selenium-reporting-with-screenshots/");
        extrpt.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Navigating to learn-automation.com..");

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        extrpt.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Title: " + title);

        try {
            Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("learn"));
            extrpt.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Step Passed");
        } 
        catch (AssertionError e) {
            extrpt.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "<pre>" + e.getMessage() + "</pre>");
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();
        extrpt.endTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: i used ExtentReports Java 1.41 and now it's working and t's not working ExtentReports Java 2.01 it is may be a bug

Comment: Version 2.01 is a complete rewrite of this API.  The usage is different.  You can go through the docs from this link:  http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/2x/docs.html. The example you posted was for 1.x versions so I provided an answer for that.  2.x has plenty of examples to get you started if you see the above link.